# Lazarus cannot run program - "debugging..." but no form shows

Tags: ide, lazarus

Until today I had no problems using the Lazarus IDE v1.0.10 32-bit under Windows 7 (64-bit).

After some work on a project, the run button (green triangle) no longer runs the application. It compiles it and the the Lazarus title bar changes to "Lazarus IDE v1.0.10 - project1 (debugging ...)" and after about a minute the title returns to normal and the run icon turns green again. At no time is an application form displayed.

If I try to run the application by pressing F7, the "Assembler" window opens. Pressing F7 again results in an error dialogue "The debugger encountered an error when trying to run/step the application. Cannot find bounds of current function. Press 'OK' to continue ...".

I can run the application (the .exe file) from a command prompt or from Windows Explorer and it displays the form and reacts normally to button presses.

- I tried creating a new project with only one form and an exit button.
- I tried uninstalling and reinstalling lazarus
- I tried restarting my computer.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lazarus had the wrong path for the debugger (gdb) in Tools -> Options -> Debugger -> General -> Debugger Type and Path.

This was because I had initially been using the 64-bit version of Lazarus and had later uninstalled it and installed a 32-bit version (in a different folder) so that I could use 32-bit DLLs for OpenSSL.

It appears the later install for some reason had found or created a reference to the earlier 64-bit install's copy of the debugger (which was the only part left after an uninstall).

Comment: I also had problems with antivirus software (avast deep screen)